# Why is the return value of integer array size(array) just 4 times the number of elements?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

For example, if I do the following,

```
int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
printf("%d", sizeof(array));
```

It would return 4 times # of elements which is 5 = 20.

But my question is don't arrays require pointers?(address)
If so, since pointers have the size of 8 bytes, why isn't it included in the size?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question quite a bit

Comment: Here's a hint, what is `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: The `sizeof` the array is the number of bytes you need to copy, assuming that you want to make of copy of the array. Any pointers that point to the array are not part of the array (i.e. there are no hidden pointers that are stored in the memory with the array). If you've been using an object-oriented language, where every object has overhead, then note a C array is not an object in the OOP sense, and has zero overhead.

Comment: An array is not a pointer, and a pointer is not an array, but an array is converted to a pointer on access subject to the four exceptions contained in [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Correct -- except that there are only three exceptions. The reference to `_Alignof` in the N1570 draft is incorrect (`_Alignof`, unlike `sizeof` cannot be applied to an expression), corrected in the published C11 standard.

Comment: @KeithThompson - learn something new every day -- that makes it a good day. Thanks.

Comment: Also, to be nitpicking, the type of the return value of operator `sizeof` is `size_t`, so you should use `"%zu"` instead of `"%d"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my question is don't arrays require pointers?(address)

Nope.  An array is just a sequence of objects - in this case, a sequence of 5 `int`:

```
       +–––+
array: | 1 | array[0]
       +–––+
       | 2 | array[1]
       +–––+
       | 3 | array[2]
       +–––+
       | 4 | array[3]
       +–––+
       | 5 | array[4]
       +–––+
```

There is no space set aside for any pointer - the *expression* `array` will be converted (“decay”) to a pointer expression such that it evaluates to the address of the first element (unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators).

> If so, since pointers have the size of 8 bytes, why isn't it included in the size?

Don’t assume pointers are a particular size - there are still 16- and 32-bit systems in use, and pointers to different types don’t have to have the same size and representation.  All the world is not <strike>a VAX</strike> x86-64.

Answer (score 0):

taking example of array[5]
for **float** and **int** type array it is showing the **size to be 20** (while the size of float is 4 and int is 2 both seems to be having same space don't know why)
so assuming a 32 bit machine having a pointer of size 4 then array is of 4*5 =20 
but for **char** type array it is showing **size to be 5**  (i.e this time not multiplied by 4 )
this time on  the same machine the pointer size must be 1 according to the output.
and for **double** type array it is showing **size to be of 40** (5*8) ,so the pointer size must be 8

that is it is not just 4 for 32 bit or 8 for 64 but it also different for different data types